# curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 30790: Connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, ambassador

I am working on a tutorial on Create a Kubernetes service to point to the Ambassador deployment.

Tutorial: https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Envoy-Ambassador-API-Gateway-for-Kubernetes.php

On running the command

```
curl $(minikube service --url ambassador)/httpbin/ip
```

I'm getting error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 30790: Connection refused
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

I can actually remove the error of

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

by running

```
minikube service --url ambassador
http://192.168.99.100:30790
```

and then

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:30790/httpbin/ip
```

I've already tried this answer [curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 31591: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009240/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-192-168-99-100-port-31591-connection-refused/55024042) also the step mentioned in this answer is already in the blog, and it didn't work.

This is the code from the blog, for ambassador-svc.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: ambassador
  name: ambassador
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v0
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  httpbin_mapping
      prefix: /httpbin/
      service: httpbin.org:80
      host_rewrite: httpbin.org
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: ambassador
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    service: ambassador
```

Can this be a problem related to VM?

Also, I tried to work on [this](https://shekhargulati.com/2019/01/24/the-2-minute-guide-to-running-ambassador-on-minikube/) tutorial first but unfortunately, got the same error.

Let me know if anything else is needed from my side.

Edit:

1.As asked in the comment here is the output of

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
```

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-qkxwm            1/1     Running   0          5h16m
coredns-fb8b8dccf-rrn4f            1/1     Running   0          5h16m
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          5h15m
kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   4          5h15m
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          5h15m
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          3h17m
kube-proxy-wfbxs                   1/1     Running   0          5h16m
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          5h15m
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          5h16m
```

after running

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/manifests/calico.yaml
```

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-78f8f67c4d-zqtl2   1/1     Running   0          65s
calico-node-27lcq                          1/1     Running   0          65s
coredns-fb8b8dccf-qkxwm                    1/1     Running   2          22h
coredns-fb8b8dccf-rrn4f                    1/1     Running   2          22h
etcd-minikube                              1/1     Running   1          22h
kube-addon-manager-minikube                1/1     Running   5          22h
kube-apiserver-minikube                    1/1     Running   1          22h
kube-controller-manager-minikube           1/1     Running   0          8m27s
kube-proxy-wfbxs                           1/1     Running   1          22h
kube-scheduler-minikube                    1/1     Running   1          22h
storage-provisioner                        1/1     Running   2          22h
```

Comment: Check you DNS pod is ready or not...Add output of **kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system**

Comment: Which network service do you used?Calico ,fannel?

Comment: I'm running the service locally on my system, i.e., by minikube. I don't think Calico and fannel are used locally. If it does, could you tell me how to find out about this network service locally?

Answer (score 0):

**kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system** should have the network service pod

So you have not set up networking policy to used for DNS.

Try using Network Policy Calico
by using command

**kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/manifests/calico.yaml**

check now **kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system**

You should get output like this :-

```
NAMESPACE    NAME                                       READY  STATUS   RESTARTS  AGE
kube-system  calico-kube-controllers-6ff88bf6d4-tgtzb   1/1    Running  0         2m45s
kube-system  calico-node-24h85                          1/1    Running  0         2m43s
kube-system  coredns-846jhw23g9-9af73                   1/1    Running  0         4m5s
kube-system  coredns-846jhw23g9-hmswk                   1/1    Running  0         4m5s
kube-system  etcd-jbaker-1                              1/1    Running  0         6m22s
kube-system  kube-apiserver-jbaker-1                    1/1    Running  0         6m12s
kube-system  kube-controller-manager-jbaker-1           1/1    Running  0         6m16s
kube-system  kube-proxy-8fzp2                           1/1    Running  0         5m16s
kube-system  kube-scheduler-jbaker-1                    1/1    Running  0         5m41s
```

Comment: I run the command as you said, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Output of
**kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system** gives as above?calico pod running?

Comment: the output was too big for the comment, please see the edits.

Comment: is this issue related to kubectl expose command? because it wasn't used in the blog.

Comment: Actually What I did is to connect with outside world..i.e try ping www.google.com, it will send packets and receive.

Comment: it resulted in time out.


ping www.google.com

Pinging www.google.com [216.58.197.68] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 216.58.197.68:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: Its DNS problem. use this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

Comment: I've tried what you said, and after running the command "kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default" I didn't get any error which tells DNS is working correctly.

kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.96.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local.
This was the output of that command.

Comment: Sorry,I don't know if any problem about ambassador..I thought problem is DNS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a checklist to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Have you created at least one **Listener** (CRD) ?
   If you don't create at least one Listener the edge-stack pod won't respond on any ports for a request. So create the **Listeners** object as reported in the official doc: 
   https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/tutorials/getting-started/
   Note that the default port defined in the Ambassador Deployment and in turn in the **edge-stack** pod are **8080** and **8443** so avoid to change them unless you know what you are doing. You can check if any existing Listener is defined with this command: `kubectl get Listener -n ambassador` or just `kubectl get Listener` if maybe you used the default namespace by mistake.
2. Have you defined at least one **Service** of type LoadBalancer which reference the Ambassador service ?
   Normally this is not needed because once you deployed Ambassador on your node you should have the Service **edge-stack** in the Namespace **ambassador** which is configured as **LoadBalancer** so it exposes some ports in the range 30000-32767 and redirect the traffic to the **8080** and **8443**. If you manually created a **Service** of type **LoadBalancer** make sure to use the right ports in the **port** and **targetPort** fields. The ports are those used by the **edge-stack** Deployment which are by default **8080** and **8443**)
3. Check that the **edge-stack** pod is responding to the request on it's port 
   The easiest way is to use the web based UI of Kubernates or your cloud provider and exec a bash into the **edge-stack** pod. With the default Kubernates dashboard you can just reach the pod, click on the vertical three dots -> Exec.
   If you are running ambassador locally you can use `eval $(minikube docker-env)`,  search the related container with `docker ps | grep edge-stack` and once you got its id you can exec the bash with the command `docker exec -it <id> bash`
   Finally run `curl -Lki http://127.0.0.1:8080` 
   You shoudl get something like this: 
   `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`
   `date: Tue, XX Xxx XXXX XX:XX:XX XXX`
   `server: envoy`
   `content-length: 0`
   If curl get a response instead of "connection refused" the service is running successfully on the pod and the problem must be in the Service, Deployment or Listener configuration. You can try to use the Cluster IP of the Service **edge-stack** instead of 127.0.0.1 but you need to run the curl command from a pod different than edge-stack. You can use your own pod or exec into the other ambassador pods which are: **edge-stack-agent** and  **edge-stack-redis**.